# Issue installing library(plyr) in R (Windows)

Tags: plyr

I have R version 3.2.2 and am working on Windows 10.  I am trying to install library(plyr), but could not install 'Rcpp' dependency (see warning in bold fonts).  Install message and warnings below.  Any suggestions?

Thanks!

> utils:::menuInstallPkgs()
>   also installing the dependency ‘Rcpp’
>
> trying URL >'https://mirrors.nics.utk.edu/cran/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/Rcpp_0.12.1.zip'
>   Content type 'application/zip' length 3189850 bytes (3.0 MB)
>   downloaded 3.0 MB
>
> trying URL 
>   'https://mirrors.nics.utk.edu/cran/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/plyr_1.8.3.zip'
>   Content type 'application/zip' length 1114768 bytes (1.1 MB)
>   downloaded 1.1 MB
>
> package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>   **Warning: unable to move temporary installation >** >‘C:\Users\xxx\Documents\R\win-library\3.2\file2e0437cc54d8\Rcpp’ to 
>   ‘C:\Users\xxx\Documents\R\win-library\3.2\Rcpp’
>   package ‘plyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>
> The downloaded binary packages are in
>           C:\Users\mydejesus\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp0yK2yD\downloaded_packages
>   library(plyr)
>   Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = 
>   vI[[j]]) : 
>    there is no package called ‘Rcpp’
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘plyr’

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a permissions setting in Windows.  I changed the permission on the folder to share with everyone and it installed successfully.